# What is the counterpart of a backbone model in parse?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I am trying to build a simple answer rating app (similar to the canonical Todo app) in Parse.

In Backbone, I could create a Model to represent a single answer and a Collection to represent a list of answers.

If I create a class in Parse's data browser, it corresponds to a Collection in Backbone. How can I specify a model (Parse.Model) in Parse.Collection if I have no way of creating one?

Comment: You are setting a backbone model in Collection.
var MyCollection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: MyModel
});

Or can you provide the goal of your answer?

Comment: @ЕгорГерасимчук:  I can create Models and Collections in Backbone. How can I do it in Parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Parse 1.2.13 (< 1.6), you can use the name of the class created in Parse Data Browser as the name of the model (individual item) in your js code.

That is, if you create a class named "Widget" in Parse Data Browser, you can use this in your js code:

```
var Widget = Parse.Object.extend ("Widget");
var Widgets = Parse.Collection.extend ({
    model: Widget
}); // example collection
```

and proceed as usual with Backbone code.